# How can I address the 10GB limit on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-search-api

We are trying to index inboxes by sitting on top of the GMail, and are using the App Engine search API, but we are hitting up the 10 GB limit. This is because we are indexing the whole organization's emails so we can search across the whole team's inbox. How can we work around this? One way might be to have an individual index per person and somehow combine the results manually, but worried that merging results might be really complex! Wondering what options are available?

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical problem in any document retrieval system, and the solution is to slice the entire corpus into multiple buckets. You should choose a slicing strategy based on your requirements/usage pattern.

One possibility is to slice messages by their date. You keep adding messages to an index until you come close to the limit, at which point you start a new index for newer messages. Or you can do it by calendar intervals (per year, per quarter or per month, depending on your volume).

Merging results from several indexes is simple. You can also give users a chance to choose how far back in time they want to go in their search. Often people know that they are looking for something recent or something that happened a long time ago.

Comment: Would the merge not get very complicated as each set of results will have their own relevance criteria and then merging these results will require you (application) to evaluate how relevant each result is? eg. it could happen that result3 from index1 is more relevant that result2 from index2 or vice versa?

Comment: Search API does not calculate "relevance" - it only returns the results that "matched" the query. If you want to evaluate relevance relative to a user-provided combination of keywords and/or phrases, you need to merge all the results and analyze each one based on whatever criteria you use to calculate relevance. Note that most email clients do not use "relevance" at all, and, therefore, users typically do not expect documents to be ranked by relevance. When I search my inbox, I expect the results to be sorted by date.

Answer (score 0):

File a feature request:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3

There was this filed too so maybe star it: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10667