# How can I debug all writes/reads to/from my App Engine Document Search?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a job that is taking emails (previously fetched) from the DataStore and putting it into a search index corresponding to the time of the email sent. It goes fine and I see results while the job is in progress. However, some time later (and this is very strange!) I see the results empty. I don't have any code to delete the results (don't need to). How can I debug this further? Is there some statistics as to when there were write ops in the search index? Also, can I get the total number of documents in any index? Then I can poll for the number. Here is the code putting the email into the search index:

```
def get_index_from_email(cls, user, raw_email_model):
        email_date = raw_email_model.date()
        userDomain = re.search("@[\w.]+", str(user.google_display_email)).group()[1:]
        index_name = (userDomain + ":" +
                      str(email_date.month) + ":" + 
                      str(email_date.day / 7) + ":" +
                      str(email_date.year))
        return search.Index(name=index_name) 

def put_message_into_index(cls, user, raw_email_model):
        d = cls._make_document(user, raw_email_model)
        index = cls.get_index_from_email(user, raw_email_model)
        try:
            index.put(d)
#             if not memcache.get(index.name+"counter"):
#                 memcache.set(key=index.name+"counter", value=0)
#             memcache.incr(index.name+"counter")
            logging.info("Put document %s into index: %s", raw_email_model.messageId, index.name)
        except search.Error:
            logging.error("Error trying to add %s to index %s", str(raw_email_model.messageId), index.name)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("Error trying to put message %s into index %s", raw_email_model.messageId, index.name)
```

Edit: Adding _make_document code:

```
def _make_document(cls, user, raw_email_model):
        if raw_email_model.is_email():
            fields = [
                      search.TextField(name='from', value=raw_email_model.from_address()),
                      search.DateField(name='sent', value=raw_email_model.date()),
                      search.TextField(name='to', value=raw_email_model.to_address()),
                      search.TextField(name='ccAddr', value=raw_email_model.cc_address()),
                      search.TextField(name='subject', value=raw_email_model.subject()),
                      search.TextField(name='messageId', value=raw_email_model.messageId),
                      search.TextField(name='threadId', value=raw_email_model.threadId),
                      search.TextField(name='content', value=raw_email_model.content()),
                      ]

            return search.Document(doc_id=raw_email_model.messageId, fields = fields)
```

and the code that queries the indexes for the results:

```
for index in domain_indexes:
                    if index:
                        logging.debug("Searching in index %s", str(index.name))
                        search_result_futures += [index.search_async(searchQuery)]
                        num_searches = 0

                searchResults = []
                for future in search_result_futures:
                    searchResults += future.get_result()
                for result in searchResults:
                    responseListItem = {}
                    for field in result.fields:
                        if field.name == "sent":
                            responseListItem["time"] = field.value.isoformat()
                        elif field.name == "content":
                            responseListItem["content"] = TeamInboxSearch.get_snippet(quote(field.value)[0][1], searchQuery)
                        else:
                            responseListItem[field.name] = field.value
                    response.append(responseListItem)
                    num_searches = num_searches + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this code on devserver? This may be a silly question for me to ask but I want to make sure - I think devserver doesn't respect persistence of search data, only Datastore (and at that, it may delete the Datastore occasionally depending on what you do).

It looks to me like you are forming your search indexes incorrectly. You are putting the data you would like to search against in the *name* of the index in `get_index_from_email`, instead of in Fields of the search document. I'm assuming your use case is that you want to be able to search for all emails from a given user within a certain time frame. You can put every email from every user in the same simply-named index, or you can name (and thus partition) the indexes according to the domain of the user's email, or a combo of user domain and year, etc... But it seems like you are forming a new search index for each possible tuple of `(userDomain, month, day, year)` that an inserted document represents.

That means your only real parameter of freedom remaining to query against is the time of day, and that doesn't seem right to me. Forgive me if this is all intentional and your use case actually is this. It's just if you stored your data all on one index, or just partitioned your documents among indexes in a more broad way, more powerful searches would be possible. You could specify the month, day, year, etc... in the *query* rather than in the name of the index. It's this that makes me think the code you are using to retrieve the documents is failing due to a misunderstanding of how to store documents.

The name of the index should be simple, or at best should be restricted to the domain you extracted from the user email, and the user email document should be created in `cls._make_document()` using various `TextField`'s and `DateField`'s to represent the time data.

At any rate, if this hasn't cleared up the issue for you, please answer back with the details about how you're running this code, and also with the code for `cls._make_document()` and the code that you use to attempt querying your index(es) to get the documents you stored.

Check out the search api documentation for python here[1]

[1] - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into it. The reason I am using the (userDomain, month, day, year) tuple is because we are putting all of the users emails into a common index.

Comment: And this is running on production, not on dev_appserver. Which surprises me. I figured the search on localhost wouldn't persist :)

Comment: And the reason for partitioning by date is because without it I was hitting into the 10GB limit on App Engine search. It was recommended on a previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26819320/2448805